# X and Y are independent normal random variables with zero mean and unity variance. Find pdf of $Z=XY^{2}$

Tags: probability

I came across these two postings: [$f(x,y)=12xy(1-y)$, $x,y \in (0,1)$. Find distribution of $Z=XY^{2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198898/fx-y-12xy1-y-x-y-in-0-1-find-distribution-of-z-xy2), and [How to deduce the CDF of $W=I^2R$ from the PDFs of $I$ and $R$ independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/how-to-deduce-the-cdf-of-w-i2r-from-the-pdfs-of-i-and-r-independent/30966#30966), and [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiO9ubB1troAhWStJ4KHczNAwEQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpldml.icm.edu.pl%2Fpldml%2Felement%2Fbwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-doi-10_7151_dmps_1146%2Fc%2Fdmps.1146.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0_UtdPa3c-6Ni39fcDVaEm).

There are a lot of high level discussions relating to some topics that are out of my knowledge level.

It looks like the derivation seems very complicated. Is there a "easier way" (the way that a beginning level student can understand) to derive the pdf of $Z$ where $Z=XY^{2}$?

Comment: The straightforward approach to try would be: figure out which pairs of $X,Y$ values correspond to the event $\{Z\le z\}$, use this to write down an expression for $P(Z\le z)$ (which is the cdf of $Z$, as a function of $z$), and then differentiate that function to get the pdf.

Comment: That is what I started with as I found this method described in one of my book example, but I get lost soon afterwards because that example is for two uniform random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Define $V=Y^2\sim \chi^2_1$
$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb P(Z\leq z)=\mathbb P(XY^2 \leq z)
=\mathbb P(XV \leq z)=\int_0^{+\infty}  P(XV \leq z |V=v) f_V(v) dv$$

$$=\int_0^{+\infty}  P(X \leq \frac{z}{v} |Y=y) f_V(v) dv=\int_0^{+\infty}  P(X \leq \frac{z}{v} ) f_V(v) dv$$

So by derivation

$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{v} f_X(\frac{z}{v} ) f_V(v) dv$$

$$=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{v} f_X(\frac{z}{v} ) 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} v^{\frac{1}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{v}{2}} dv$$

$$=\int_0^{+\infty}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{z^2}{v^2}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} v^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-\frac{v}{2}} dv$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}   
 v^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-\frac{v}{2}-\frac{z^2}{2v^2}} dv$$

Now you need to solve the integral.